# Query to get sum of quantity for each different location from following screenshot

Tags: mysql

[image]

Table should be like :

```
Factory1  DC_Westbengal  2000..........
Factory1  customer6      1000..........
Factory1  DC_Hyderabad   1000
```

Comment: group by the 2 columns and sum on the third..

Comment: Please share your database schema. This should be a very straightforward query, something like  `SELECT Name, Loc, SUM(QTY) FROM <tableName> GROUP BY Name, Loc`. p/s: You might want to stop using a pirated copy of MS Office.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html)

```
SELECT Name, Loc, SUM(QTY) AS QTY
FROM dbo.tablename 
GROUP BY Name, Loc
```